# Extra space under textarea, differs along browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, whitespace, removing-whitespace

There`s some extra space under textarea tag. From 1 to 4 pixels in different browsers. The markup is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .main {
                background-color: red;
            }
            textarea {
                background-color: gray;
                resize: none;
                margin: 0;
                border: 0 none;
                padding: 10px;
                height: 50px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's how it is rendered in browsers:

[image: Screenshot]

Why is this happening? How to remove this extra space?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `textarea`.

The reason for the gap is that `textarea` is an `inline` (or `inline-block`) element, and the gap is the space reserved for [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) in text. I don't know exactly why the gap is different between different browsers.

Comment: Have my children

Comment: It always feels so validating when a couple hundred other people have the same problem as me, .

Comment: Ten years later. This is still a thing.

Comment: This solved my problem, but after that the textarea's bottom was too close to the next textarea bellow, so I fixed it adding "margin-bottom: 1px;".

Comment: @thirtydot, why not `bottom` and `middle`?

Comment: @Pacerier: Any of them work, I probably picked the shortest one.

Answer (score 28):

In my case, **thirtydot**'s answer didn't work well with the parent `<div>`'s bottom border.

`display: block` suited me nicely though.

Comment: This worked well for me, too.

Answer (score 2):

I also found that the space goes away if the textarea's parent is using `display:flex`:

```css
/* The relevant part: */
#FlexLayout { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

/* The boring part: */
.ShowChildBorders * { border: 1px solid; }
#DefaultLayout * { border-color: red; }
#FlexLayout * { border-color: green; }
#SideBySide { display: flex; }
#SideBySide > div { flex: 1; margin: 4px; }
#SideBySide * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="SideBySide">
  <div class="ShowChildBorders">
    <div id="DefaultLayout">
      <div>Default Layout</div>
      <textarea>Text Area</textarea><br/>
      <textarea>Text Area</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ShowChildBorders">
    <div id="FlexLayout">
      <div>Flexbox Layout</div>
      <textarea>Text Area</textarea>
      <textarea>Text Area</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On Chrome 91.0.4472.77, Windows 10 64-bit, that renders as:

| [image] |
| --- |