# Extra padding under text area

Tags: html, css

My text area has extra padding under it but I cant seem to find the source of it. I have put the individual code on this page:

http://jsfiddle.net/wfuks/

I cant seem to find the source of it. It has class "field":

```
.field { background-color: white; width: 430px; padding: 10px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; }
```

Any input (pun) would be appreciated :)

Comment: .field has padding:10px. remove it

Comment: If you formatted and organised your css better, this sort of thing would be easier to spot.

Comment: Do you want to remove the padding under the text area, or inside the text area?

Comment: I am talking about the fact that the space between the input box and the gray container box is bigger at the bottom than on the top.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extra space under textarea, differs along browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144843/extra-space-under-textarea-differs-along-browsers)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To have cross browser no white space below textarea/input fields use:

```
textarea,
input,
select {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

(tested in your fiddle, works)

Oddly the vertical align is the key here.

Just a note, you don't need the margin:0 because you already have `*{margin:0}`.
For an even more complete cross browser experience for textarea you could also use `overflow:auto;` for IE and `resize:none;` for browsers with resizing support.

Some more info about why it works like it works:
[Mystery white space underneath image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444891/mystery-white-space-underneath-image-tag/31445364#31445364)

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto` to `.field_box` and `float:right` to `textarea`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wfuks/4/)**

In your code there is `float:left` to label, in that case the right element should have the right floating to fill the exact space available. otherwise you can remove floats and achieve this by using `display:table-row` and `table-cell`

---

And yes even `vertical-align: bottom` works.

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wfuks/7/)**

Comment: +1 This solution works. A little explanation would be good :)

Comment: My solution works as well and is in my opinion much more subtle and has less(no) chance of breaking anything else in the page. About why floats work: floats have the habit of becoming a block element with a special set of rules. In this case setting it to `display:block` works as well. It's just ugly. And display:block works because block elements don't have white space from line-height like inline elements have. In a nutshell, it's the long way around.

Comment: Sorry for long comments: I'm not saying you shouldn't use any float here. It's just not the best general purpose solution for removing the added white space on the bottom of a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you mean the padding in the `div class= 'field_box'`. Make the padding to `0px` in this class to remove the space under text area.

If you mean the padding in the text area: make padding= 0px in class `.field`

Comment: It should be 4px all the way around but it is more at the bottom. I want it to be 4px at the bottom not more.

Comment: yes in chrome I find the difference. However Mozilla shows it correctly