# What's the white space under textarea by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a simplified of my code:

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is a whitespace under the `textarea` (something like `5px` of `margin-bottom`) which is all by defaul. Since I have never styled the textarea nor the outer div.

So, how can I remove that space? Noted that, giving `margin: 0px;` to the textarea won't work.

Comment: didn't you check this answer [Extra space under textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144843/extra-space-under-textarea-differs-along-browsers)

Answer (score -1):

You can update your div css codes like this:

```
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}
```